# Required auth to download a Google Meet recording

Tags: google-drive-api, google-calendar-api, google-meet

I'm working on an integration to stream Google Meet recordings to a 3rd party file storage service.  Here's the rough workflow I'm following

1. Create the meeting using the Google Calendar API
2. During the meeting, a user optionally records
3. After the meeting, check the calendar event description for a link to the generated Google Drive file
4. Use the Drive API to retrieve a download link for the file
5. Open a download stream and stream to 3rd party service

My question is what OAuth scopes I need to make this work.  The `drive.file` scope will only give me access to files my app created.  The meeting recordings are created by Google Meet.  The `drive.apps.readonly` scope gives me access to all files if the user installs my app.  Could I create a Google Workspace Marketplace app and use that scope to download the file?  Will the `downloadUrl` in the file object work with a token that only has `drive.apps.readonly`?

I'm trying to avoid using any restricted scope if possible.

Answer (score 0):

#### Drive scopes are restricted by design

If you check this page, [About Auth](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/about-auth), and this page, [OAuth Verification FAQs](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914) you'll see that Drive is inherently restricted due to the nature of the service. Since your app does not create the video, it will require a restricted scope to fetch the video created by meet.

I believe that `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` will work for your purposes.